# Why are some bakashot made on Shabbat?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, torah-service

As I understand it, we don't make prayers of request (bakashot) on Shabbat (cf [Rambam Shabbat 30:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3130.htm#12)).
For that reason, we omit so many liturgical requests because of shabbos - e.g., Avinu Malkeinu, tachanun, the 13 attributes, singing during birkat kohanim, most of the amidah.

If that's so, then why are we allowed to make requests during the Torah service - e.g., mishebeirach, birkat hachodesh, yekum purkan, Kel malei rachamim, prayer for the country, prayer for Israel?

Comment: I know of some shuls that don't do many of these things for exactly this reason. (I think benching after al y'chasrenu can also be included in this catagory)

Comment: This article is a must on the topic: http://books.google.com/books?id=_QshqTu9nGIC&pg=PA153&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @soandos there are shuls that don't do birkat hachodesh?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, there might be, but I have not heard of them. I imagine that is different, as it is based off of a d'oritah I believe (but am not sure, and I don't think that the bakashot are part of the mitzvah per se in any case)

Comment: @DoubleAA That's a terrific article!  Just skimmed a bit of it.  Will look at it more throughout the day.  Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman yekkes do not say the yehi rotzon, nor the long yechadesheinu, of birchas hachodesh because it is bakashos.

Answer (score 3):

Taking out the Torah constitutes an eit ratzon, a time appropriate for making requests to the King Whose presence we have invoked.

Here's another article about it which elaborates on the concept of eit ratzon and why this supercedes the general issue of not making requests on Shabbat:
http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2010-06-04_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf

The whole point is that the eit ratzon appropriate for making requests on Shabbat depends on taking out the sifrei Torah.