# Why are רצה and שים שלום classified as thanksgiving and not as petitionary?

Tags: tefilla, rambam, shemoneh-esrei, anshei-knesset-hagedolah, shevach-bakashah-hodaah

Rambam writes regarding the makeup of shemoneh esrei ([tefilah 1:4](https://rambam.alhatorah.org/Full/Tefillah_uBirkat_Kohanim/1.4#e0n6)) that

> שָׁלֹשׁ רִאשׁוֹנוֹת שֶׁבַח לַה' וְשָׁלֹשׁ אַחֲרוֹנוֹת הוֹדָיָה. וְאֶמְצָעִיּוֹת יֵשׁ בָּהֶן שְׁאֵלַת כָּל הַדְּבָרִים שֶׁהֵן כְּמוֹ אָבוֹת לְכָל חֶפְצֵי אִישׁ וָאִישׁ וּלְצָרְכֵי הַצִּבּוּר כֻּלָּן
>
> The first three [blessings] are praises of God and the last three are thanksgiving. The intermediate [blessings] contain requests for all those things that serve as general categories for the desires of each and every person and the needs of the whole community.

מודים seems to be the only of the latter 3 that can rightfully be termed thanksgiving.

The other two seem to be ברכי בקשה/petitionary blessings and no different than say תקע בשופר or את צמח דוד to take two examples.

Why are they categorized as thanksgiving and not petitionary?

(Fascinatingly, after posing this question, I came across Rashba to bavli berachos 34a where he quotes R Hai Gaon who was more lenient with bakasha additions in the latter 2/3 berachos vs the first 3 for this exact reason:
הא דאמר רב הונא לעולם אל ישאל אדם צרכיו בשלש אחרונות. כתב רב האי גאון ז"ל דהני מילי צרכי יחיד אבל צרכי רבים שואלין, דהא כל שלש אחרונות שאלת צרכי רבים נינהו, ואפילו תרצה לפניך עבודתינו דהוו אמרי במקדש צורך הוא, ושים שלום נמי תביעת ציבור הוא. אלא מיהו אף על גב דהכין, שלש ברכות ראשונות לשבח הן אמורות ואין בהם מקום תביעת צורך לא ליחיד ולא לצבור ולא מהוגן לרבנן אפילו מאן דאמר זכרנו לחיים באבות ומאן דאמר זכור רחמיך בהודאה, ואפילו מאן דאמר בחנוכה ופורים כמו שעשית נסים לראשונים כן תעשה נסים לאחרונים. והני מילי לאו רגילי במתיבתא למימרינהו ע"כ. Cf. Tosafos ad loc s.v. אל ישאל)

Comment: Possible repeat: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27901/is-the-bracha-of-retzei-avodah-a-bakasha

Comment: There's a few definitional points here. הודיה could be more related to וידוי or even like וידוי מעשר. Second, the old conclusions for the brachot are שאותך לבדך ביראה נעבוד and מעון הברכות עושה השלום which are less requesty and more acknowledging God as the Ultimate target of service and source of blessing (peace is the paradigmatic blessing, uktzin 3:12). But that just moves your question of the difference from בקשה to שבח, though it's less "god is great" and more acknowledging the situation/relationship.

Comment: @DoubleAA see תוספתא מנחות ו:ו
הלל ושבח ותפלה מעכבות זו את זו where הלל is used synonymously with הודיה

Comment: @Nahum That's a nice connection but I'm not convinced it's really pshat in the tosefta.

Answer (score 3):

The Sefer Abudraham asks this question in the beginning of the second gate.
ואם תאמר והלא ברצה ושים שלום מבקש הוא פרס מרבו כמו באמצעיות. ויש לומר שאינו דומה כי אמצעיות הם צרכי האדם, ושלש אחרונות כלם כבוד קב"ה כגון העבודה שנעבדנו. וכן ההודאה זו היא כבודו וכן השלום. ועוד כבוד הוא לרב שהרבים צריכין לו.
I can’t say I fully understand the distinction, but essentially he says the earlier brachos are for man’s needs whereas שם שלום and רצה are for G-D’S honor.

Comment: Wow. Great find. Tysm! As you say it needs ruminating on.