# How can we make requests for personal needs in Rosh Chodesh "Bentching"?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, rosh-chodesh-new-month

On Shabbos before Rosh Chodesh we ["Bentch" the new month between Shacharis and Mussaf](http://ou.org.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/tt/5769/months69.pdf). Seeing that it is Shabbos, [when Chazal forbade one to ask for his personal needs](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue2.pdf)  how can we make these requests, especially those in bold?

> And give us long life, a life of peace, of good, a life of blessing,
>   **a life of sustenance, a life of health,** a life marked by the fear of Heaven and the dread of sin, a life free from shame and reproach,
>   **a life of prosperity and honor**, a life in which the love of the Torah and the fear of Heaven will be in us, **a life in which the
>   desires of our heart shall be fulfilled for good**

Comment: Your second link discusses this.

Comment: related/dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18510/759

Comment: Dupe! (Other question is better too!)